# How to use helm values to pass in values to a config file that is not in the templates directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a config file that is external to the `templates/` directory in my Helm chart (config.yaml is located at the root of my project). For example, I need to pass this config file into the creation of a secret in my templates directory. I need to use the values.yaml file to edit the ep1, ep2, and ep3 hard-coded values before being referenced n the secret resource creation. From my understanding, the values.yaml file does not templatize files outside of the templates directory:

```
- job_name: 'broker-1'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['ep1:11001', 'ep2:11001', 'ep3:11001']
- job_name: 'broker-2'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['ep1:11002', 'ep2:11002', 'ep3:11002']
```

I am using the below to create the secret, where I reference the file name that the above config is located:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: config-file
data:
  {{- $root := . -}}
  {{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "config.yaml" }}
  {{ base $path }}: '{{ $root.Files.Get $path | b64enc }}'
  {{- end }}
```

I am trying to use `tpl` to enable this, but have not had any luck. I am testing using the below:

```
- job_name: 'broker-1'
  static_configs:
  - targets: {{ .Values.endpoints1 }}
- job_name: 'broker-2'
  static_configs:
  - targets: {{ .Values.endpoints2 }}
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: config-file
data:
{{ tpl (.Files.Glob "config.yaml").AsSecrets . | indent 2 }}
```

but with this, the secret contains the literal values that are in the file as referenced above

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the real problem you're running into is that the Secret data is normally base64 encoded.  If you look at some of the examples, and the output of `helm template`, you're probably expecting to get output like

```yaml
data:
  config.yaml: LSBqb2JfbmFtZTog...
```

If `.Files.Glob.AsSecret` base64 encodes the data, then you won't have a chance to run `tpl` over it.

Probably your first approach is closer to what you need to do: in the middle of the pipeline where you call `b64enc` there is a point where you have the plaintext untemplated data, and *there* you can call `tpl`.

I'd write this slightly differently, not using `.Files.Glob` only for a single file, getting something like:

```yaml
data:
  config.yml: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "config.tpl") . | b64enc }}
```